# Why does "Modify Border" bleed outside the selected edges?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6

I have a problem with my Photoshop fill feature.

I created a selected area with a border of 2. Then I **Edit** → ***Fill...*** but it seems to bleed outside the lines with a faint colour. It's best I show the screen shot so see below:

This is my selected area:

[image]

This has a **Select** → **Modify** → ***Border...*** (1px)

Then i do **Edit** → ***Fill...*** and this is the result:

[image]

Notice the fill is bleeding outside the selected area - why is this? Is there some option I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just what **Select** → **Modify** → ***Border...*** does. From the help docs:

> #### [Create a selection around a selection border](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-76f0a.html#WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-76e6a)
>
> The new selection frames the original selected area, and is centered on the original selection border. For example, a border width of 20 pixels **creates a new, soft-edged selection** that extends 10 pixels inside the original selection border and 10 pixels outside it.

If you are simply trying to create a border, there are much better ways (such as applying a stroke as a layer effect)

Comment: Ah thats annoying... what is the best option to do instead as i don't want the soft edge.

Comment: @Dave I've edited my answer. If you don't know how to do that, google "photoshop apply stroke". Another way would be to use **Edit** → ***Stroke...***, but I'd recommend the layer effect (an effect is easier to modify)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to realize that the photoshop selection can be soft. And the "walking ants" indication only shows the 50% threshold. So there can be pixels outside the visible selection edge that are nevertheless selected 40% or so.

You could have done a 50% threshold modification on your selection prior to filling, or create the edge selection by selecting the outer rectangle, and then (holding alt key) unselect the inner rectangle.

There are other ways.